# Android Studio 3.1 Default or static interface method used without --min-sdk-version >= 24

Tags: android, android-studio, android-architecture-components

I have recently updated my Android Studio to 3.1 and I am starting receiving this error:

> Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N
>   (--min-api 24): void
>   android.arch.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver.a(android.arch.lifecycle.h)
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Default interface methods are only supported
>   starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void
>   android.arch.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver.a(android.arch.lifecycle.h),
>   sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Here is my app `build.gradle` file contents:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 11
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

I am also using following Android Architecture Components:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

Besides this, I am also using Gradle build tools version `3.1.0` and Gradle version is `4.4`.

After searching a bit on similar issue, I have also tried this in project `gradle.properties` **without luck**:

```
android.enableD8=true
```

Everything works fine in Android Studio 3.0, but as soon as I upgraded to 3.1 I started receiving this error.

Comment: What Gradle version are you using? 4.4?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini yes 4.4

Comment: Did you try with this: `android.enableDesugar=false`

Comment: I think it comes from the “special” `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1”`. Just for fun, have you tried the “normal” `annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1”` ? I know it’s not the same, but it may be a bug in the library :) (I’m reading https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini cool that works... But I am using Java8 and curious to have its solution. :)

Comment: Did you previously use jack. Do you have a `jackOptions` section in your gradle file? Jack didn't support default interface methods.

Comment: I’d love to know too, so I wrote this as an Answer for future ppl. If we get to the bottom of it, I’ll keep the answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be a problem with their “special” implementation for Java 8 and min-apis. `android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1`.

Try the “normal” annotationProcessor `android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1`.

I know it’s not the same, but it may expose a bug or a limitation of the library. Or perhaps your `grade` file has some old option?

My initial advice would be to create an EMPTY project with the same dependencies and see if you can make it work there.

It will make it easier to report to issues.google.com if needed.

Source:  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html